# Opening PDF after printing it with CutePDF

Tags: windows-xp, cutepdf

Is there an option somewhere hidden that makes the PDF file automatically open after being printed out with CutePDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the direct answer to your question, but some years ago I switched from CutePDF to [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) and the latter can be both flexibly programmed from VB/VBA/C#, is completely free and has an option whether to open newly created documents or not. So, if this feature is crucial for you, consider using this printer.

Comment: Heey, that's not bad :) ..... if no one comes with a direct answer to my question in a few hours/day or two, I'm accepting this one and moving to Bullzip. +1 for now ...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Switched to Bullzip a while ago - small differences, but well worth the change! Thanks mate!